# Fetching Captured Image sent through Intent

Tags: android, android-intent, position, android-arrayadapter, android-bitmap

I'm working on a simple project, where I'm suppose to create an application for taking notes. I've sucessfully created the app but now I want to make it possible for the user to take a photo and save it with the note. 
I can take the picture, preview it, and then click save. 
But the problem is that I'm not able to get the image sent through the intent to my MainActivity class, where the note is suppose to be saved.

**So my question is how do I save the note with the picture, please look at the picture that represents how I want my customRow to look like**
[image]

I have no idea why this happends beacuse I get no errors... And its been driving me nuts. 
Any ideas??

**Image.class**

```
public void capturePhoto(View view){
        Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        fileUri = getOutputMediaFileUri();
        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri);

        // start the image capture Intent
        startActivityForResult(intent, CAPTURE_IMAGE);
    }
 @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

        switch (requestCode){
            case CAPTURE_IMAGE:
                previewCapturedImage();
                break;
        }

    }
    else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
        // user cancelled Image capture
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                "User cancelled image capture", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                .show();
    } else {
        // failed to capture image
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                "Sorry! Failed to capture image", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                .show();
    }

}
private void previewCapturedImage() {
    try {
        // bitmap factory
        BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();

        // downsizing image as it throws OutOfMemory Exception for larger
        // images
        options.inSampleSize = 2;

        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(fileUri.getPath(),
                options);

        //Set image here
        imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

 public void sendImageAsIntent(Boolean isSending){
    if(isSending = false){
       isSending = true;

    }
    if(isSending = true) {
        Intent i = new Intent(CheckOutMemo.this, MainActivity.class);
        i.putExtra("filePath", fileUri.getPath());
        setResult(RESULT_OK,i);
        finish();
    }
}
```

**MainActivity.class**

```
 @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (resultCode != Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        return;
    }
    if (requestCode == Image.ADD_REQUEST_CODE) {
        String header = data.getStringExtra("header");
        String bodyText = data.getStringExtra("bodyText");

        filePath = data.getStringExtra("filePath");
        sourceFile = new File(filePath);
        fileName = data.getStringExtra("filePath");
        Uri imageUri = data.getData();
        if(filePath!=null) {
            try {
                Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(),imageUri);
                imageIcon.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "FileNoutFoundException MainActivity", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "IOException MainActivity", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }


        Memo memo = new Memo(header, bodyText,imageIcon);
        customAdapter.add(memo);
        customAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    } else if (requestCode == Image.EDIT_REQUEST_CODE) {

        int position = data.getIntExtra("position", 0);
        Memo memo = customAdapter.getItem(position);
        memo.header = data.getStringExtra("header");
        memo.bodyText = data.getStringExtra("bodyText");
        customAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

}
```

Comment: "I'm not able to get the image sent through the intent to my MainActivity class" -- please explain what you mean by this.

Answer (score 1):

When you do:

```
Intent i = new Intent(CheckOutMemo.this, MainActivity.class);
i.putExtra("filePath", fileUri.getPath());
startActivity(i);
```

You are basically asking to create a new instance of `MainActivity`. To return to the previous activity while setting the result do this instead:

```
setResult(RESULT_OK, i);  
finish();//finishing activity
```

Comment: Thank you @Shaishav. This time at least I got an error. 

java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=1, result=-1, data=Intent { cmp=com.dahlstore.dnote5/.MainActivity (has extras) }} to activity {com.dahlstore.dnote5/com.dahlstore.dnote5.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException

at MainActivity.onActivityResult (MainActivity.java:116) 
Row 116 is my: 
Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(),imageUri);

I updated the code above

Comment: I'm guessing my fileUri.getPath() is empty when sending it as an Intent right?